# Link text is Unclear error even when <a> tag has descriptive links. ( tota11y)

Tags: accessibility, khan-academy

I have a  tag, which has the following structure

`<a href="#" ng-click="generatePlanTasks()">Regenerate</a>`

Even though it has the descriptive links, tota11y throws an error "Link Text is unclear".

I am not able to figure out why it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not reproducible with the recent version of tota11y.